# Why is conmon in a different cgroup when podman is started with systemd?

Tags: systemd, docker, cgroups, container

Given podman is installed on a linux system and a systemd unit named baz.service:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/baz.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/podman run --rm --tty --name baz alpine sh -c 'while true; do date; sleep 1; done'
ExecStop=/usr/bin/podman stop baz
```

And the baz.service started:

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl start baz.service
```

Then when I check the status of the unit I don't see the `sh` or `sleep` process in the /system.slice/baz.service cgroup

```
# systemctl status baz
● baz.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/baz.service; static; vendor preset: enabl
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-08-10 05:50:18 UTC; 14s ago
 Main PID: 16910 (podman)
    Tasks: 9
   Memory: 7.3M
      CPU: 68ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/baz.service
           └─16910 /usr/bin/podman run --rm --tty --name baz alpine sh -c while
# ...
```

I was expecting to see the `sh` and `sleep` children in my baz.service status because I've heard people from redhat say podman uses a traditional fork-exec model.

If podman did fork and exec, then wouldn't my `sh` and `sleep` process be children of podman and be in the same cgroup as the original podman process?

I was expecting to be able to use systemd and podman to be able to manage my containers without the children going off to a different parent and escape from my baz.service ssystemd unit.

Looking at the output of `ps` I can see that `sh` and `sleep` are actually children of a different process called `conmon`. I'm not sure where conmon came from, or how it was started but systemd didn't capture it.

```
# ps -Heo user,pid,ppid,comm
# ...
root     17254     1   podman
root     17331     1   conmon
root     17345 17331     sh
root     17380 17345       sleep
```

From the output it's clear that my baz.service unit is not managing the conmon -> sh -> sleep chain.

- How is podman different from the docker client server model?
- How is podman's conmon different from docker's containerd?

Maybe they are both container runtimes and the the `dockerd` daemon is what people people want to get rid of.

So maybe docker is like:

- dockerd daemon
- docker cli
- containerd container runtime

And podman is like:

- podman cli
- conmon container runtime

So maybe podman uses a traditional fork exec model but it's not the podman cli that's forking and exec, it's the conmon process.

I feel confused.

Comment: There is discussion about this question on the podman mailing list: https://lists.podman.io/archives/list/podman@lists.podman.io/thread/GPDO23XMMTLRWVZB6RI2HDVJUTICEY54/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The whole idea behind `podman` is to go away from the centralized architecture with the super-powerful overseer (e.g. `dockerd`), where the centralized daemon is a single point of failure. There even is a hashtag about this - "**#nobigfatdaemons**".

How to avoid the centralized container management? You remove the single main daemon (again, `dockerd`) and start the containers independently (at the end of the day, containers are just processes, so you don't need the daemon to spawn them).

However, you still need the way to

- collect container's logs - someone has to hold `stdout` and `stderr` of the container;
- collect container's exit code - someone has to `wait(2)` on container's PID 1;

For this purpose, each podman container is still supervised by a small daemon, called `conmon` (from "container monitor"). The difference with the Docker daemon is that this daemon is as small as possible (check [the size of the source code](https://github.com/containers/conmon/tree/master/src)), and it is spawned per-container. If `conmon` for one container crashes, the rest of the system stays unaffected.

Next, how the container gets spawned?

Considering that the user may want to run the container in the background, like with Docker, the `podman run` process forks **twice** and only then executes `conmon`:

```
$ strace -fe trace=fork,vfork,clone,execve -qq podman run alpine
execve("/usr/bin/podman", ["podman", "run", "alpine"], 0x7ffeceb01518 /* 30 vars */) = 0
...
[pid  8480] clone(child_stack=0x7fac6bffeef0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tid=[8484], tls=0x7fac6bfff700, child_tidptr=0x7fac6bfff9d0) = 8484
...
[pid  8484] clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_VFORK|SIGCHLD <unfinished ...>
[pid  8491] execve("/usr/bin/conmon", ... <unfinished ...>
[pid  8484] <... clone resumed>)        = 8491
```

The middle process between `podman run` and `conmon` (i.e. the direct parent of `conmon` - in the example above it is PID 8484) will exit and `conmon` will be reparented by `init`, thus becoming self-managed daemon. After this, `conmon` also forks off the runtime (e.g. `runc`) and, finally, the runtime executes the container's entrypoint (e.g. `/bin/sh`).

When the container is running, `podman run` is no longer required and may exit, but in your case it stays online, because you did not ask it to detach from the container.

Next, `podman` makes use of cgroups to limit the containers. This means that it *creates new cgroups for new containers and moves the processes there*. By the rules of cgroups, the process may be the member of only one cgroup at a time, and adding the process to some cgroup removes it from other cgroup (where it was previously) within the same hierarchy. So, when the container is started, the final layout of cgroups looks like the following: `podman run` remains in cgroups of the `baz.service`, created by `systemd`, the `conmon` process is placed in its own cgroups, and containerized processes are placed in their own cgroups:

```
$ ps axf
<...>
 1660 ?        Ssl    0:01 /usr/bin/podman run --rm --tty --name baz alpine sh -c while true; do date; sleep 1; done
 1741 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/bin/conmon -s -c 2f56e37a0c5ca6f4282cc4c0f4c8e5c899e697303f15c5dc38b2f31d56967ed6 <...>
 1753 pts/0    Ss+    0:02  \_ sh -c while true; do date; sleep 1; done
13043 pts/0    S+     0:00      \_ sleep 1
<...>

$ cd /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/machine.slice
$ ls -d1 libpod*
libpod-2f56e37a0c5ca6f4282cc4c0f4c8e5c899e697303f15c5dc38b2f31d56967ed6.scope
libpod-conmon-2f56e37a0c5ca6f4282cc4c0f4c8e5c899e697303f15c5dc38b2f31d56967ed6.scope

$ cat libpod-2f56e37a0c5ca6f4282cc4c0f4c8e5c899e697303f15c5dc38b2f31d56967ed6.scope/cgroup.procs 
1753
13075

$ cat libpod-conmon-2f56e37a0c5ca6f4282cc4c0f4c8e5c899e697303f15c5dc38b2f31d56967ed6.scope/cgroup.procs 
1741
```

Note: PID 13075 above is actually a `sleep 1` process, spawned after the death of PID 13043.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "creates new cgroups for new containers and moves the processes there"
I don't understand why podman is doing that work instead of systemd. Can you add an explanation about why we use conmon to hold stdout and stderr instead of systemd? From learning about systemd I thought the purpose of systemd is to manage processes and do tasks like capture stdout/stderr, figure out the exit status, handle restart.

Comment: Podman manages cgroups because it owns the container and has to guarantee that the container will work disregarding what init system do you have. Systemd manages cgroups for services because it owns services (and services are not supposed to manage cgroups by default, though systemd supports some kinds of delegation - see https://systemd.io/CGROUP_DELEGATION). If you want podman to reuse the cgroups created by systemd for the service, there must be a support from the podman side, and I currently don't see one (though I may err).

Comment: As to `stdout`/`stderr` streams - again, `podman` owns the container and captures the streams of the containerized process. `systemd` owns the service and captures the streams of the service's main process (in your case, `systemd` actually captures `stdout`/`stderr` of the `podman run` process). This works exactly as it should work, because `conmon` captures the streams of the container, `podman run` attaches to `conmon`, `systemd` captures the streams of `podman run`, so, finally, all logs from the container get captured by `systemd`, and you see them in `systemctl status baz.service`.

Answer (score 1):

podman with `--cgroups split` will create the cgroups in a more systemd-friendly way. (Similar to how systemd-nspawn would do it, with a "service" cgroup, and sub-cgroups for supervisor and container processes)

Example - my rwhod container:

```
 CGroup: /machine.slice/rwhod.service
         ├─container
         │ ├─ 998 /dev/init -- /container/tool/run
         │ ├─1040 /usr/bin/python3 -u /container/tool/run
         │ └─1706 /usr/sbin/rwhod -i mgmt0 -S -D
         └─supervisor
           └─995 /opt/podman/libexec/podman/conmon --api-version 1 -c ddf3e27960378fd57b2ebd15d7beb7474506f612e7329acb014c5f89cd652562 >
```

I was part of adding that method to podman specifically for this purpose, as part of this very log discussion. https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/6400